# why unity says i cant call "GetKeyDown" on a mono behaviour?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

My code does not raise any errors but when i test it in unity it wont work here is the code, i just want to make a simple movement code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class player : MonoBehaviour
{


private void start()
{
  

 

}

void update()
{

  if (Walk_right) 
   transform.position += Time.deltaTime * Walk_speed * Vector3.right;

  if (Walk_left) 
   transform.position += Time.deltaTime * Walk_speed * Vector3.left;

  if (Walk_up) 
   transform.position += Time.deltaTime * Walk_speed * Vector3.forward;

  if (Walk_down) 
   transform.position += Time.deltaTime * Walk_speed * Vector3.back;

  
}

[SerializeField] private float Walk_speed = 5f;
[SerializeField] private float Run_speed = 10f;
[SerializeField] private bool Walk_right => Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D);
[SerializeField] private bool Walk_left => Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A) ;
[SerializeField] private bool Walk_up => Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W) ;
[SerializeField] private bool Walk_down => Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S);
```

}

The first time i tried unity editor said I couldn't call "GetKeyDown" on a Monobehaviour, but the tutorial I have seen uses the same logic and works plus these errors messages suddenly disappeared. Can someone point out what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Set break pointer to  see how it work?

Comment: 'update()' -> 'Update()' How about that ?

Comment: Unrelated to the issue but I would remove `SerializeField` attribute from the last 4 variables (`Walk_right`, ... etc.) since Unity isn't able to serialize [properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the 'void update' and 'void start' 'to void Update' and 'void Start'.
Capitalize the first letter of the words as they are the function names.
Predefined function names are case-sensitive. Hence, Unity cannot identify the function name the way you have written it, due to this the commands given by you are ignored and not executed.

Also, one thing I would like to point out, Type the variable names before the start method. It is not necessary but definitely, the way the majority of people go with it.
Example:

```
public class player : MonoBehaviour
{
[SerializeField] private float Walk_speed = 5f;
[SerializeField] private float Run_speed = 10f;
[SerializeField] private bool Walk_right => Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D);
[SerializeField] private bool Walk_left => Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A) ;
[SerializeField] private bool Walk_up => Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W) ;
[SerializeField] private bool Walk_down => Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S);

private void Start()
{
  
//Start Code here
}

private void Update()
{
//Update Code here
}
```

Comment: But what's exactly wrong with the function name? why does unity cannot identify it?

Comment: @danielsantos You have typed the whoe name in lower-case. The first letter of the function name is supposed to be Upper-Case. like 'Update' instead of 'update'. Just like I added in the example.

Comment: oh got it mate thanks for helping a newbie!

Comment: @danielsantos Most welcome, I am a newbie as well. Remember to accept it as answer if it helped to solve your problem. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to change update and start as Update and Start. Unity use Pascal case in function name.